# How to configure a STOMP Transformer for OpenMQ/Glassfish

Tags: glassfish-3, stomp, transformer-model, openmq

I have wrote a basic Message Transformer to Transform object messages to Text messages.
I am not Java/OpenMQ/Glassfish Expert

The Transformer compiles fine BUT now I need to configure the STOMP Bridge to use it...
I cant find any examples online on how to do it.

I copied my StompTransformer.class to 
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext
and All the required jars to: 
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\applibs  (not sure if this is the right place)

I added the following into config.properties:

```
imq.bridge.admin.user=admin
imq.bridge.stomp.messageTransformer=StompTransformer
imq.bridge.admin.password=admin
imq.bridge.activelist=stomp
imq.bridge.enabled=true
```

I tried to read the documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19587-01/821-0027/gjdnl/index.html >>> *Configuring a JMS Bridge*

**but it is confusing to me :( I don't know what should be in the XML file, what it should be called, where I should put it and what else is needed for configuration.....**

**Here is the code for the Transformer:**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.jms.*;
import com.sun.messaging.bridge.service.MessageTransformer;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

 public class StompTransformer extends MessageTransformer <Message, Message> {

 public Message transform(Message message, 
                          boolean readOnly,
                          String charsetName,
                          String source, 
                          String target,
                          Properties properties)
                          throws Exception {

    Message m = message;
    if (source.equals(SUN_MQ)) { //from Java Message Queue to STOMP client

        if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {

            //create a new TextMessage for message to be transformed to
            TextMessage tm = (TextMessage)createJMSMessage(JMSMessageType.TEXTMESSAGE);

            //convert message to the TextMessage
            XStream xstream = new XStream();
            tm.setText(xstream.toXML(message));
            m = tm;
        }
    }
    return m;
 }
}
```

Comment: Which version of OpenMQ are you using?

Comment: Have you tested it with a stand-alone OpenMQ installation instead of GlassFish 3 (GF introduces more possible configuration errors, while a stand-alone OpenMQ keeps GF out of the way)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a choice. It is for integration with another system from another vendor (QMatic Queuing) I need to capture queuing events and summarize it for a dashboard application but the Queuing events are of type ObjectMessage and my application is not java

Comment: I am using OpenMQ 4.5.2 and GlassFish 3.1.2 (build 23)

Answer (score 0):

With OpenMQ 4.5.2 (running stand-alone, not embedded in GlassFish) I tested the message transformation with this project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.habarisoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>OpenMQMessageTransformer</artifactId>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>imq</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>                                            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>imqjmsbridge</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And this transformer class:

```
package com.habarisoft.mqtr;

import java.util.*;
import javax.jms.*;

import com.sun.messaging.bridge.service.MessageTransformer;

public class StompTransformer extends MessageTransformer<Message, Message> {

    @Override
    public Message transform(Message message,
            boolean readOnly,
            String charsetName,
            String source,
            String target,
            Properties properties)
            throws Exception {

        System.out.println("transform ...");

        Message m = message;
        if (source.equals(SUN_MQ)) { //from Java Message Queue to STOMP client

            if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {

                //create a new TextMessage for message to be transformed to
                TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) createJMSMessage(JMSMessageType.TEXTMESSAGE);

                tm.setText("<converted object>");
                m = tm;
            }
        }
        return m;
    }
}
```

The generated JAR must be in the lib/ext directory together with other required dependency Jars (note that this has been tested with a stand-alone Open MQ installation).

and this broker configuration for the STOMP bridge:

```
imq.bridge.admin.user=admin
imq.instanceconfig.version=300
imq.bridge.stomp.messageTransformer=com.habarisoft.mqtr.StompTransformer
imq.bridge.admin.password=admin
imq.bridge.activelist=stomp
imq.bridge.enabled=true
```

Then I started a STOMP client listening for incoming messages in queue TOOL.DEFAULT, and used a JMS client to generate object messages:

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;
import javax.jms.Session;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {

        ConnectionFactory cf = new com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory();

        Connection conn = cf.createConnection("admin", "admin");
        conn.start();

        Session session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue queue = session.createQueue("TOOL.DEFAULT");
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);

        Date date = new Date();

        ObjectMessage msg = session.createObjectMessage(date);
        producer.send(msg);
        conn.close();

    }
}
```

If the JMS client code sends an object message while the STOMP client is listening, the console window where the broker runs successfully writes the

```
transform ...
```

message. But then it logs an error, complaining about a null JMS destination:

```
Dez 10, 2014 8:04:39 AM
WARNUNG: [BSS2009]: Nachricht ID:8-192.168.56.1(ea:8a:dc:e5:15:7c)-58027-1418195
079856 kann nicht an Abonnent {98F4744E-6E12-44CC-8336-36A9BA7CDC77} ausgeliefer
t werden: JMS destination null !
javax.jms.JMSException: JMS destination null !
        at com.sun.messaging.bridge.service.stomp.StompProtocolHandler.toStompDe
stination(StompProtocolHandler.java:832)
        at com.sun.messaging.bridge.service.stomp.StompProtocolHandler.toStompFr
ameMessage(StompProtocolHandler.java:893)
        at com.sun.messaging.bridge.service.stomp.StompConnection.toStompFrameMe
ssage(StompConnection.java:438)
        at com.sun.messaging.bridge.service.stomp.StompSubscriberSession.onMessa
ge(StompSubscriberSession.java:127)
        at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.MessageConsumerImpl.deliverAndAcknowl
edge(MessageConsumerImpl.java:358)
        at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.MessageConsumerImpl.onMessage(Message
ConsumerImpl.java:287)
        at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.SessionReader.deliver(SessionReader.j
ava:119)
        at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ConsumerReader.run(ConsumerReader.jav
a:192)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Dez 10, 2014 8:04:39 AM
```

I have not investigated this further, but it looks like more code is required to construct the transformed message than is shown in the [OpenMQ JavaDoc for the transformer](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.mq/imq/4.5.2/com/sun/messaging/bridge/service/MessageTransformer.java).

But test results show that the transformer is called and the provided example can be used as a starting point.

---

Update:

If the system architecture is under your control, then it might be easier to insert a Java (JMS) client application in the message flow, which transforms the object message to a text message and re-sends it to a distinct destination, which the STOMP client consumes.